# How to run vim with plugins?

Tags: vim

I followed [guide for vim with python](https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/), that means:

```
1. I added all plugins to .vimrc;
2. Installed plugins with vim-command :PluginInstall.
```

But when I open project like **$ vim /path/to/project** or some file, I get nothing: no plugins on fire or any settings from **.vimrc**.

Can you help me with what I do wrong and how run vim with my plugins? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need at least install a plugin manager like [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) before running:

```
:PlugInstall
```

So, you have to follow the instructions on the plugin's page.

Answer (score 1):

`:PluginInstall` command is from the vim plugin manager "[Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)".
Without a plugin manager, cloning / copying plugin files and updating them is really hard. What Vundle (Vim-bundle) does is, it reads your plugin requirements from ~/.vimrc file, and manages them for you.

To start with Vundle,

1. Run

`git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

to clone Vundle into your .vim directory.

2. Add your plugin requirements in to .vimrc (Follow the .vimrc template in the [Vundle official repository quick start section](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start))
3. Inside vim, type `:PluginInstall` and hit enter. Colon mark initiates vim commands.
4. After the installation is complete, restart vim.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't needed a plugin manager since vim 8.0. The easiest way to install a plugin called foo.vim if you do not care about updating it:

1. In your vimfiles directory, where your vimrc is, create this directory structure `pack/plugins/start/foo/plugin`
2. Copy your plugin file in that directory, so it is located in `~/vimfiles/pack/plugins/start/foo/plugin/foo.vim` assuming you use `vimfiles` and not some other directory
3. A different plugin would be in `pack/plugins/start/bar/plugin/bar.vim`

Done. Undoubtedly easier than using a plugin manager, and without the additional overhead.

If you want to keep your plugin updated, simply clone the git repository to the `start` directory and update with `git pull`.

Read more here:
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/03c3bd9fd094c1aede2e8fe3ad8fd25b9f033053/runtime/doc/repeat.txt#L515