# Log file highlighting for vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In VIM I would like to highlight my files ending with extension `.log` as shown below

[image]

I tried installing https://github.com/MTDL9/vim-log-highlighting .

Vim version = IMproved 8.0

.vimrc file = https://github.com/aseem-hegshetye/vim_setup/blob/master/.vimrc

**UPDATE**

Following steps got me a certain highlights structure shown in an image below, but not as good as what I am looking for :

1. create ~/.vim/syntax/log.vim from this file:
   https://github.com/dzeban/vim-log-syntax/blob/master/syntax/log.vim
2. Create ~/.vim/ftdetect/log.vim from this file:
   https://github.com/MTDL9/vim-log-highlighting/blob/master/syntax/log.vim 
   [image]

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run vim with plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46695637/how-to-run-vim-with-plugins)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+PlugInstall

Comment: I was able to install the plugin but still I dont see any highlighting for log file in VIM

Comment: @Aseem What's your Vim version and features? Please post the output of `vim --version` (or `vi --version` if you call it by the `vi` name), or also `:version` from inside it. Please post it as text! Also post your vimrc or the relevant parts of it. Other than installing the plug-in, you also need to enable filetype handling (with `filetype plugin indent on`) and syntax highlighting (with `syntax on`) in your vimrc file, so make sure that's there.

Comment: I have edited the question to provided all information you asked for